# ANTLR how to create optional spaces in grammar?

Tags: parsing, antlr

We are writing an ANTLR grammar for a language, and want to strip out optional spaces.

For example, suppose I have the following function call type thing:

```
f(x=2)
```

We want to be able to define it with any number of spaces (including no spaces) before and after each token, so that the following are all legal

```
f ( x = 2 )
f    (    x = 2)
f (
  x =
2 )
```

It seems natural to define a space tag S that is ignored, because we don't care where it is.

How should this be done in ANTLR? The following mwe creates a fragment S, but ANTLR complains whenever S is put into a production that is not a token.

```
grammar mwe;

func: 'f' S '(' S VAR S '=' S VAL ')' S
    ;

VAR:        [a-zA-Z]+;
VAL:        [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
fragment S: [ \t\n]*;
```

Comment: This sounds like a formatting problem, not a parsing problem. Unclear what you want. Formatting is easy with Antlr, but the real problem is identifying how you want to reformat the input. For example, do you want rewrite newlines with spaces? Multiple spaces with one space? Do you want to perform reindentation? I would use Antlr and codebuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fragment` is for setting up partial Lexer rules to be used to close Lexer rules.  So you really don't want `fragment` for your `S` rule.

What you're looking for is the `skip` directive.  This tells ANTLR to create the token, but to "skip" that token when evaluating parser rules.  This means that you don't need to specify all the. locations where the `S` token might appear in your parser rules.

Try:

```
grammar mwe;

func: 'f' '(' VAR '=' VAL ')'
    ;

VAR:        [a-zA-Z]+;
VAL:        [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
S: [ \t\n]+ -> skip;
```

Comment: Perhaps mention that `VAL` will never be created?

Comment: @Bart I fixed the bug in the original question to match the desired text. IS that what you mean?

Comment: This solution generates the warning non-fragment lexer rule S can match the empty string
is that ok? It is just skipping

Comment: You probably don't need it matching an empty string.  Use `+` instead of `*` (I'll amend answer.)